# How can I handle an url with double slashes in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-router

For legacy reasons I am required to handle a route where there is potential for there to be two slashes back to back because there is an optional id in the path (e.g. /base//child/2). I can not change the url in anyway (like omitting the double slashes in favor of a secondary route). Is there anyway I can get the angular router to recognize this url and either redirect it or handle it?

This [minimal stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/double-slashed-routing) shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Angular can not parse url with double slash correctly, so the routing path mapping will not work. You can implement your own `UrlSerializer` instead of using the default `DefaultUrlSerializer`. Try to convert path "/base//child/1" to "/base/child/1".

```
import {UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  parse(url: any): UrlTree {
    let dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    console.log(url);
    if(/\/\//.test(url)) {
      url = url.replace(/\/\//, '/');
    }
    return dus.parse(url);
  }
  serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
    let dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer(),
    path = dus.serialize(tree);
    return path;
  }
}
```

Register it in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';
import { CatchAllComponent } from './catch-all/catch-all.component';
import { InformedComponent } from './informed/informed.component';
import { CustomUrlSerializer } from './custom-url-serializer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{
      path: 'base/child/:id',
      component: InformedComponent,
    }, {
      path: 'base/:parentId/child/:id',
      component: InformedComponent
    }, {
      path: '**',
      component: CatchAllComponent
    }])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CatchAllComponent, InformedComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now the url with double slash "//" will be converted to "/". It will match the routing path "base/child/:id", so you can get the params and handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try with [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) something along these lines

matcher.ts

```
import { UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

export function matcher(url:  UrlSegment[]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(url));
 return url.length === 1 && url[0].path === 'base' ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

routes

```
import  { matcher } from './matcher';

RouterModule.forRoot([{
  matcher: matcher,
  component: InformedComponent
}, {
  path: 'base/:parentId/child/:id',
  component: InformedComponent
}, {
  path: '**',
  component: CatchAllComponent
}])
]
```

Tried this with your stacknblitz and it works. Not sure but other options could be listening to router's navigation started event or a route guard.

Comment: This does kind of work, but it omits all the information after the double slashes (putting it into the stackblitz the right component loads, but the id information is lost). I am still playing with it to see if I can get this method to work since it has the benefit of being pretty specific and not overriding global configuration.

Comment: so what did you end up doing ?

Comment: I did a pathmatch full on the base route and used a canActivate guard to redirect after parsing window.location manually (which I am not proud of and don't want to submit as an answer) to one of the child routes with the correct values.

I don't like it much and am still hoping to find something more angular.